# What happened to ANTLR3.1's HIDDEN Channel in ANTLR3.5?

Tags: antlr3

An 3.1.1 grammar of ours contains (with target language C#) this snippet:

```
WHITESPACE 
  : ( '\t' | ' ' | '\r' | '\n'| '\u000C' )+     { $channel = HIDDEN; } 
  ;
```

When compiling, this now leads to a compile-time error. The Antlr3.Runtime of ANTLR3.5.2 is, of course, referenced in the project.

Can anyone tell me what changed here from 3.1.1 to 3.5.2? Thanks!

Comment: Have you considered reading the documentation?

Comment: I have not only considered it, but actually did it. All the examples I found (may have been not everywhere) use HIDDEN, and none of the change logs from 3.1.x to 3.5.x contained something that made me aware of the change. But yes, it's my fault.

Comment: Well if it wasn't in the change logs, that's fair enough, but if you did read the docs *it's useful to mention as much* in the question.

Comment: In other words, it is assumed that people dont RTFM :) - well.But actually, the documentation at https://theantlrguy.atlassian.net/wiki/display/ANTLR3/ANTLR+v3+printable+documentation contains only examples with "HIDDEN", none with "Hidden".

Comment: Then you should see if you can raise an issue with the developer to update the docs. Sadly, far too many people fail to do any research before asking here (e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/33015896/3001761), so if you don't *show any* in the question itself, expect people to assume you didn't do any!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It changed along the way to conform with C#'s naming conventions into `Hidden`:

```
{ $channel = Hidden; }
```